# Modelling two different tables

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have Visit and Consult table both are related through table Patient.
i.e The visit and Consult table have foreign key patient_id. I have to
edit this two tables (Visit and Consult) on a single edit action.i.e
in edit view both tables data should display.
What model I have to use?
Thanks.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three tables should have separate models and be related via the [Cake PHP Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

In your case (as I understand) you have the following associations:

```
Patient hasMany Visit     (via Visit.patient_id)
Patient hasMany Consult   (via Consult.patient_id)
Visit belongsTo Patient   (via Visit.patient_id)
Consult belongsTo Patient (via Consult.patient_id)
```

When you have  these defined in the appropriate places in the three models (Patiend, Visit and Consult) and if you have followed the [CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions) if you want to see all this data for e.g. in the Patients Controller edit() action you could do:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Patient->id = $id;
    if ($this->Patient->exists()) {
        $patient = $this->Patient->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
    }
}
```

Now $patient will contain the Patient record and all of it's associated records from the 
Visit and Consult models in a nice array structure (provided a Patient with this id exists of course).

From what you say I am not certain if you understand the CakePHP Model associations.
Check out the links.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, 
   Borislav.

Comment: Oh, yeah this is for CakePHP 1.3 because the question was tagged with it. ;)

Comment: Thanks yoyr reply...It helps me a lot